# Split 1 in to n parts of size $2^{-k}$

Tags: probability-theory

I have the following problem:
Let $n \geq 2$. Let $p_{i} = 2^{-k_{i}}, k_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. 
$$p_{1} \geq p_{2} \geq ... \geq p_{n}$$
and $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i} = 1$$

**I have to show the following:** $p_{n-1} = p_{n}$

I tried a lot but still I don't seem to get anywhere near the answer. Could someone give me a hint( I'd prefer finishing the proof myself :)).
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can solve this exercise in a fun way using the binary number system :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_{n-1} \gt p_n$, then $k_n \gt k_{n-1}$. Write sum as $$p_n = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{p_i}$$ Multiply both parts by $2^{k_n}$. Then left part is $1$(odd), right ... You can finish now.

Answer (score 1):

Show that everything, except perhaps $p_n$, is a multiple of $p_{n-1}$